# Within ASP.Net MVC, how do I show and hide 3 @Html.ActionLink buttons on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Within ASP.Net MVC, how do I show and hide 3 `@Html.ActionLink` buttons on click?

Basically, I'm trying to code the mobile-side of a website but my webpage 6 `@Html.ActionLink` Buttons and I don't want these buttons to fill the entire page so what I'm wanting is for when the webpage detects that a mobile is viewing the website (`@media screen and (max-width: 480px)`) the last 3 buttons are hidden and a button called more will appear.

This new button on click will reveal the last 3 buttons and when clicked again will hide them.

I've not done this before, but my attempt is below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#more").on('click', function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementById('Extra');
    var isHidden = buttons.style.display == 'none';
    buttons.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
#more {
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #more {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  nav li:nth-of-type(5) {
    display: none;
  }
  nav li:nth-of-type(6) {
    display: none;
  }
  nav li:nth-of-type(7) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="center">
  <nav>
    <ul id="menu">

      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Page1", "Page1", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Page2", "Page2", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Page3", "Page3", "Home")</li>
      <li id="more">@Html.ActionLink("More", null, null, new { @id = "more" })</li>
      <li id="Extra">@Html.ActionLink("Page4", "Page4", "Home")</li>
      <li id="Extra">@Html.ActionLink("Page5", "Page5", "Home")</li>
      <li id="Extra">@Html.ActionLink("Page6", "Page6", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
     <script type="text/javascript">
  
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#more").click(function(){
     $(".Extra").toggle();
    }); 

});

  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="center">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">

                        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                        <li id="more"><a href="#">More</a></li>
                        <li class="Extra" style="display:none"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                        <li class="Extra" style="display:none"><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
                        <li class="Extra" style="display:none"><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```